# How do I create a TfvcLabel using TfvcHttpClient in Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

We are a team trying to upgrade our windows application to use Azure DevOps Services' new REST based .NET Client Libraries instead of Client OM that uses SOAP.

The part of the application that we are upgrading does the following:

1. Checks out all `AssemblyInfoVersion.cs` files.
2. Updates the version on those files.
3. Checks in all the files.
4. Create a Label with information about that the version was updated.

We managed to do the first three steps with the new REST based .NET Client Libraries using the `CreateChangesetAsync` method.

But we can not find any information about how to create a Label so we have not been able to do the last step. Is this really not supported?

Answer (score 1):

Currenlty you can't create a new label with the new Azure DevOps Rest API, you can [only get labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/labels).

As workaround, you can use `tf.exe` with the command [label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/9ew32kd1(v=vs.80)) to label the files.

In your code add something like this (using `System.Diagnostic`):

```
string tfExePath = "path/to/exe";
string tfArgs = "label test /version:45 $test/src"
Process.Start(tfExePath, tfArgs)
```